# error: "net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_acct" is an unknown key

Tags: networking, debian, iptables, firewall, sysctl

I have the this error when I run `sysctl -p` in Debian 5.0.8.

> error: "net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_acct" is an unknown key

My sysctl configuration

```
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_acct = 1
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_max = 9527600
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established = 7200
```

Output of `lsmod`

```
ipv6                  289352  34 
loop                   19724  0 
nf_conntrack_ipv4      19352  0 
nf_conntrack           71440  1 nf_conntrack_ipv4
joydev                 15232  0 
evdev                  14592  0 
ext3                  125456  3 
jbd                    54696  1 ext3
mbcache                13188  1 ext3
raid1                  24832  4 
md_mod                 81700  5 raid1
thermal_sys            17728  0
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's saying that you have a setting `net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_acct` in your `/etc/sysctl.conf`, but when sysctl tries to load that setting it has no idea what it is.  Did this used to work in the past?  Maybe you installed a new kernel which does not support that sysctl.

EDIT: based on your comment about the kernel version you are using, it looks like your older Debian does not support that sysctl.  See [this debian mailing list thread](http://lists.debian.org/debian-kernel/2009/09/msg00422.html) for details - looks like it was added in 2.6.29.

You will have to recompile your kernel or upgrade to enable that feature.

Comment: i used in centos, its the first time in debian  2.6.26-2-xen-amd64